# Question about calculating $2^{32101}\bmod 143$?

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to calculate $2^{32101}\bmod 143$ with using paper and a calculator. 
What bothers me is that $32101 = 47 \times 683$ and $143=11 \times 13$, so they are not prime numbers. This means i can't use Fermat's little theorem. I tried also to solve it by square and multiply algorithm, but i am stuck there too, so maybe it doesn't work too. 
I have been thinking of using the Chinese reminder theorem, but i don't know how to apply it here, because of the prima facorization of $32101$...

Does anyone have an idea how to calculate suche large numbers when they are not prime? 
I would be glad if someone could help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: To use CRT you just need to think about the prime factorization of $143$, not of $32101$. The numbers $11$ and $13$ are quite small, and you can certainly reduce $32101$ modulo $11-1$ and $13-1$ (i.e. use little Fermat *locally* then patch a global solution mod $32101$ via CRT).

Comment: 3\,mod\,2 looks like this: $3\,mod\,2$.  3\bmod2 looks like this: $3\bmod2$.  I changed it to that standard usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you already thought about using Fermat's Little Theorem and Chinese Remainder theorem, which combined *can* do this.

The basic idea is that you can compute

$2^{32101} \pmod{11}$ and $2^{32101} \pmod{13}$ using Fermat's Little Theorem, and then use the results to compute $2^{32101} \pmod{143}$ using Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: For the more general case, [Euler's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) is what you want when the modulus isn't prime.

Comment: I think now i finally got it. So i calculated first $2^{32101 \bmod\varphi (11)} \bmod 11 = 2^{32101 \bmod 10}\mod 11= 2^{1}\bmod 11\equiv 2$ and then $2^{32101 \bmod\varphi (13)} \bmod 13 = 2^{32101 \bmod 12}\mod 13= 2^{1}\bmod 13\equiv 2$. Then i apply the Chinese Reminder Theorem and get $2^{1}\times 2^{1} \mod (11\times 13)\equiv 2\times 2 \Rightarrow 2^{1} \mod 143\equiv 2$, so i reach my desired result $2$. Is this correct now? Thank you!

Comment: Yep, that sounds solid.

Comment: Thank you very much, Dennis!

Answer (score 1):

Square and multiply should work. The calculation is long enough that it's easy to have made a mistake, though, if you aren't careful. I usually wind up doing long calculations twice (hopefully with variations in the two tries -- e.g. one calculation might use the bottom-up variation and the other the top-down variation) to get some extra confidence I didn't make an error.

You could break mod 143 into mod 11 and mod 13, and do those individually, then recombine to get an answer.

The base and modulus are relatively prime, so you could use the generalization of Fermat's little theorem:

> If $\gcd(b,m) = 1$, then $b^{\varphi(m)} \equiv 1 \bmod m$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

Comment: Thank you! I solved it exactly this way :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) to find $$\lambda(143)=60$$

$$\implies 2^{60}\equiv1\pmod{143}\implies 2^{60a}\equiv1^a\pmod{143}\equiv1\text{ for any integer }a$$

Now, $32101\equiv1\pmod{100}$ and $32101\equiv1\pmod3$

$\implies 32101\equiv1\pmod{\text{lcm}(100,3)}\implies 32101\equiv1\pmod{300}$

$\implies32101\equiv1\pmod{60}$

Comment: I haven't heard of Carmichael function before, but what i love about this site, is that one can always learn something new :) I really appreciate all the different ideas that you, guys, gave me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The factors of $32101$ really don't matter.  What is to be done is to note for example, that $2^{12} = 1 \pmod{13}$, and $2^{10} = 1 \pmod{11}$, so $2^{60}= 1 \pmod{143}$, where $60 = \operatorname{lcm}(12, 10)$,

So, you can put $2^{60}x = x \pmod{143}$, and thus freely subtract multiples of $60$ from $32101$.  This equates to $2^{32101} = 2^1 \mod{143}$, because subtracting multiples of 60 from 32101 equates to $32101 = 1 \pmod{60}$.

So then it's the simple task of evaluating $2^1 = 2$, which is the desired answer.

Comment: But we have $2^{32101}$ and not $3^{32101}$ :)

Comment: fixed. @Lullaby thanks :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea! :)